# positioning a background on a link and make it scalable as well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to setup my layout on the `mobile-first` way. In the orange area [here](http://www.bootply.com/5Ire2TbPMf#) I have a link with `class="logo"`. But for some reason the logo does not appear at all.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 bg bg-blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 bg bg-orange">
                <a href="/" class="logo">test</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 bg bg-white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 bg efrat"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some relevant CSS

```
.bg-orange {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  background-color: #f7942e;
  height: 25%;
}
.bg-orange a.logo {
  background: url(//placehold.it/480X91) no-repeat center;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

For the full example please see: [here](http://www.bootply.com/5Ire2TbPMf#)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What's your current code for that part?

Comment: `text-indent: -9999px;` of course you can't see the text!

Comment: I added some relevang code. @dfsq it's not about the text. It's about the background image. The text should not be visible.

Comment: @sanders http://www.bootply.com/Gd7qhsbEkr You can't see the image because `a` has zero dimensions. You need to give it height/width.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for the reply. How could this be made scalable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us some of YOUR's code... But for that. also you must display a as block or something similar for background:url work.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
.bg-orange a.logo {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/480X91") no-repeat center;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:480px;
  height:91px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```